# Relation between inner product spaces and topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

How inner product spaces are related to topological spaces? I know that an inner product space is a topological space but does it mean that need to use the Euclidean metric to define the topology of a cube and another metric for a sphere?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE.  An inner product induces a norm, which induces a metric, which induces a topology

Comment: Your question seems quite broad to me, and I can't quite understand what you are after.  If you have a space with an inner product, that inner product induces a norm, and the norm gives rise to a metric.  A metric induces a topology.  This seems, maybe, to answer the question?  But I don't see what this has to do with spheres and cubes?

Comment: Sorry i might be a bit confused about the subject since i'm trying to learn it by myself. From what i understood topological spaces are the most general spaces used for describing geometric concepts. Since i know that there is this connection from inner products to topological spaces i was wandering how different inner products affect the topology induced.

Comment: I'm not sure that I would say that a topological space is the most general space for describing geometry.  Topological spaces are places where one can discuss analytic concepts like limits and continuity.  If you want to discuss geometry, you need some additional structure, such as a metric (which describes distance), or some (local?) notion of an inner product (which can be used to describe orthogonality and angle).  A Riemannian manifold might be the right place to discuss geometry.